# How do I extract the public key from private key in c#?

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle

I **only** have a private key in a pem file and need to extract the public key from it.

At the moment I'm using openssl for this:

```
openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER
```

Ho can I do the same in c# (and Bouncycastle)?

Comment: Huh? That's not the one I wanted to post *at all*. Sorry about that, try the link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26948066/589259). My apologies for the weird link. Would you be helped with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26948066/589259) and then just setting the modulus and public exponent? <- redo from start.

Comment: I'm thinking in the direction of reading the PEM with Bouncy Castle and then using `RSAParameters` to generate the public key. If you also want to use Bouncy to perform the RSA operation then you are already done on step 1 of course.

Answer (score -1):

In windows world file that contains private key is called PFX.
So you can try to import certificate to collection using .net System.Security.Cryptography infrastructure:

```
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import(filePath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
```

The code block was taken from here:
[How to retrieve certificates from a pfx file with c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036590/how-to-retrieve-certificates-from-a-pfx-file-with-c)

Comment: I have a pem file, which contains only the private key.

Comment: @LouisHaußknecht as far as I know a pem file is a container specifically formatted and includes a certificate. So public key should be in.

Comment: @LouisHaußknecht and by the way, try to open pem file in a text editor. It is possible to see the structure, at least I can see -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- in my test file, so even new X509Certificate2(filePath) would work to get public key.

Comment: @FireAlkazar Again, I only have a pem file with a private key.

Comment: @LouisHaußknecht ok, not expecting simple solution then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10216712/1479335

Answer (score -2):

If your .pem file already contains the public key it is usually between the Lines

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and

```
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

of the pem file.

At least Openssl does it like this, but you should check it carefully. 
See [this](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem) link for an overview over the structure of a pem file.

So you could get it by using the `Substring` method. This should work:

```
static void ExtractPublicKeyFromPem(string path)
    {
        var startText = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
        var endText = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

        var pem = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        var start = pem.LastIndexOf(startText);
        var end = pem.IndexOf(endText);

        var publicKey = pem.Substring(start, end - start);
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I only have a pem file with the orivate key.

Comment: Then , why you don't simply use the openSsl Runtime to do the work?